# Fail to preview Widget in Xcode with SwiftUI Preview

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui, widgetkit

I am trying to preview some View by using Widget context, like:

```
struct MyTasksView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
            MyTasksView(
                myTasks: Fake.myTasks,
                user: Fake.user,
                error: ""
            )
            .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemMedium))
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting this error while attempt to run the preview. And, I'm not sure why it is happing.

> RemoteHumanReadableError: Unknown preview provider “MyTasksView_Previews”
> MyApp does not contain a preview provider named “MyTasksView_Previews”. Check your build settings to ensure the preview provider is compiled into your product.

I, also, tried to use a simple `Text(text).previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemMedium))`, but it did not work either. I'm using the Xcode beta 5.

In Apple Emoji Rangers Demo App for WWDC 2020. We can see this piece of code for preview:

```
struct CharacterNameView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CharacterNameView(CharacterDetail.panda)
            .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemSmall))
    }
}
```

[image: Emoji Rangers example]

Comment: have you tried with the Xcode beta 6?

Comment: Yes, same error :(

Comment: I failed to display any widget preview using their EmojiRangerWidgetEntryView on any of the three targets in the final sample code. they even had article on how to display with previews, but their example code didn't work

Answer (score 13):

I had the similar issue and I solved it by putting the View inside a VStack (or another container).

Here is my code that worked:

```swift
struct WidgetViewPreviews: PreviewProvider {

  static var previews: some View {
    VStack {
      WidgetView(entry: .mock)
    }
    .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemSmall))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's a bug in Xcode, you can only use previewContext of "single" Widgets Target.
So you need to unselect other Targets.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this one works for me.

Comment: this did not work, the file im previewing only selects the extension.

Answer (score 1):

Add `Widget extension` target, and activate it. For more information
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/creating-a-widget-extension

Comment: That will not resolve this issue for everyone.

Comment: Was helpful for me together with solution from alfred zh

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when adding widgets extension to my UIKit app.

Changing the Class target membership to widget extension solved this for me.